# design element for chat box in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How i can design chat Box UI in xamarin.forms with the small edge outside the box like in screenshot [image]

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: for the rounded rectangle i used frame ...but not getting any idea for that corner edge ...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make renderer to create a bubble like that.

Here you can find an entire chat application made in Xamarin: https://github.com/EgorBo/CrossChat-Xamarin.Forms

Here you can find the Android renderer:
https://github.com/EgorBo/CrossChat-Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Client/Crosschat.Client.Android/CustomRenderers/MessageRenderer.cs

IOS renderer:
https://github.com/EgorBo/CrossChat-Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Client/Crosschat.Client.iOS/CustomRenderers/MessageRenderer.cs

And the winows renderer:
https://github.com/EgorBo/CrossChat-Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Client/Crosschat.Client.WinPhone/CustomRenderers/MessageRenderer.cs

GOod luck

Comment: I am currently working on it...there are some issues i m getting while building sol...let me come out of it

Comment: What issues are you getting?

Comment: Could you provide de stacktrace / innerexectpion perhaps?

Comment: InspectorDebugSession(8): HandleTargetEvent: UnhandledException
An unhandled exception occured.

Comment: I/Adreno-EGL(25572): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/09/15, 6cbbf7d, I3193f6e94a
I/OpenGLRenderer(25572): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/Mono    (25572): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
D/Mono    (25572): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'.
D/Mono    (25572): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'.
D/Mono    (25572): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'.
D/Mono    (25572): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').

Comment: D/Mono    (25572): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'.
D/Mono    (25572): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'.
D/Mono    (25572): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'.

Comment: You''l need to catch the exception in a try catch so you can get the innerexception of it.

Comment: @priya_d do you have working code for chat bubble?